# garbage collector doubts

Tags: java, garbage-collection

I have some question over here regarding the java garbage collector.
First let me clear what I have understood regarding the `Java GC.`
`GC` is a background thread will always run in the background when the JVM starts.
Each object having one finalize() method. This method is used to release the
system resources before the object is destroyed. According to java experts,
we should not put the resources under finalize() method for releasing the 
system resources. Becuase we cannot make sure when the GC will run. But we can
request the `GC` to run  by calling `System.GC()`.

So now my question is, `GC` is  a background thread will always run in the background.
Now how can we say that we dont know when the `GC` will run? Is the statement like this `"we dont know when the GC will call finalize() method "`
Is that the meaning of that? If that is what they meant, then what is the job
of `GC`? `GC`'s responsibility to find out the un used variable and remove from the memory.
In that case,why `GC` cannot call finalize() method also?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Now how can we say that we dont know when the GC will run?.

Functioning of GC is dealt by complex Algos, which is dependent on underlying OS and Hardware. WE can't say because if one tell about a particular JVM version it will not be valid with other JVMs. So it better we can't rely on that.

> what is the job of GC.

GC finds reference less objects (read type of ref. for more) and reclaims memory used by them.

> n that case,why GC cannot call finalize() method also?

So that's sure finalize method will be called but it's not sure when. Because evenif you know in your JVM when finalize() method will run, you never know when in other JVMs. So, if you deal with some really expensive resources in your finalize method, your programe may crash in other JVMs.

Comment: can we make sure that one object is no longer required, will be freed from memory? In that case, why cant finalize() method called and free the system resources?

Comment: You can't make sure. You can only make it only eligible for GC by rendering it ref-less. finalize() method will be called but you are not sure when

Comment: -1 because the JVM Spec does place conditions on automatic storage management, ie. the garbage collector. The JLS and JVM Spec are written to ensure the cross-platform nature of Java just for the reason that ambiguity of platform is never a concern.

Comment: well..you are saying every JVM will behave similarly doesn't matter which underlying platform is. I was not talking  about ambiguity rather consistancy in their behavior across platforms. Also we have different different JVM implementation even for a single platforms

Answer (score 0):

Simply put, GC will run at an indeterminate time, so system resources would not be freed in a timely manner if `finalize` is relied on to free them. It doesn't make sense to wait for the GC to reap the heap space of an object holding a system resource when most program logic should be easily designed to simply release the resource when it is no longer in use.

On a somewhat related note. One of the issues that caused early versions of the JVM to be so slow was calling `finalize`. Thus, modern JVMs will skip calling `finalize` whenever possible. So relying on `finalize` could also have a performance impact.

Comment: can we make sure that one object is no longer required, will be freed from memory? In that case, why cant finalize() method called and free the system resources?

Comment: It can. It is valid to rely on `finalize` to be called, but not what is typically done. You can read the spec, chapter 12.6 - http://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se7/html/jls-12.html#jls-12.6